# What is the best way to give SAAS subscribers their own A Record for logging in to their dashboard?

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, dns, saas

The title should be pretty clear, but consider this scenario:

- User bobbyflay registers an account on my SAAS app
- I would like for the URL bobbyflay.myapp.com to direct him to a customer-specifi login page.

I'm developing on CodeIgniter 2.0.2 for what it's worth. Is there a better way than modifying the routes.php config file every time a new account is created?

Comment: @mhambra What about it? Nothing about this prevents load balancing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is exactly the article you're looking for.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/)

Note it is written for an older version of CI but the methodology should be intact.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wildcard record in your DNS that resolves all *. DNS lookups to a single IP address, then identify the specific subscriber using the Host header sent from the browser.

EDIT: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

If you plan to implement this, at least consider disabling it via options; either "profile exists" or "profile not exists, hidden or disabled" messages should appear at accessing the subdomain - else your client's security/privacy may be harmed.

Comment: how would this affect customer security/privacy?